# Blowing the shofar in an "older" large shul

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

Mishnah Rosh Hashanna 3:7 says:

> One who blows into a pit or a cistern or a jug, if he heard the sound
>   of the shofar, he has fulfilled his obligation, but if he hears the
>   echo, he has not fulfilled his obligation.

This rule of not fulfilling the mitzvah of hearing the shofar if one hears an echo is not unique to blowing in a pit, but any place that may have an echo.

The shul I grew up in was (is) an "older" shul with high ceilings and it definitely produced a huge echo. This was wonderful in terms of hearing the chazzan. But, I'm curious if such large shuls like this or those that have special "acoustic paneling" that both produce large echoes would be problematic for most of the congregants on Rosh Hashanna. Not everyone can sit close to where the shofar blower is when the shul is crowded.

Is there a "measurement" or "distance point" that someone or other criteria in such shuls where one would not fulfill his obligation because he is hearing an echo? Or, can we assume that any place within the confines of the shul would be fine and people are most likely hearing the actual shofar sound, and the echo is "negligible"?

Comment: It's clear from the meforshim on the Shulchan Aruch that we only worry about the echo for those standing outside of the room/location where the shofar is, but those in the same location are [mainly?/dominantly?] hearing the original shofar. . See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.587.1?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he